# Getresponse v3 api -add contact error

Tags: php, api, getresponse

I use getreponse php client (https://github.com/GetResponse/getresponse-api-php/blob/master/src/GetResponseAPI3.class.php) to add a contact to a list.

```
$fname ="mike";
$lname = "";
$email = "mike@test.com";

$getresponse = new GetResponse('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$response = $getresponse->addContact(array(
'name'              => $fname . " " . $lname,
'email'             => $email,
'dayOfCycle'        => 0,
'campaign'          => array('campaignId' => '999999999')
));
```

I am getting this error when I try this code:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (7) { ["httpStatus"]=> int(403) ["code"]=> int(0) ["codeDescription"]=> string(38) "Internal error, please contact support" ["message"]=> string(58) "Access Forbidden! You have no access to campaign: 9999999" ["moreInfo"]=> string(46) "https://apidocs.getresponse.com/en/v3/errors/0" ["context"]=> array(0) { } ["uuid"]=> string(36) "503b85fb-799c-46ec-b297-" }
```

I have the correct API key and campaign id.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using campaign name in Your request please use campaign token.
You can get list of campaigns including tokens using this api method:

https://apidocs.getresponse.com/en/v3/resources/campaigns#campaigns.get.all

its working on my end with out any problem

Comment: I tried with campaign token. It is not showing error now. But the contact is not listed in the campaign. Any idea?

Comment: if you want to show the list of subscriber then you need to use this

https://apidocs.getresponse.com/en/v3/resources/contacts#contacts.get

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is not working for you.. But its working very well.. I was searching this code from last 3-4 days.

I downloaded sdk file from github which you mentioned. Later I did following codings. This is alteration I did:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/getresponse-api/src/GetResponseAPI3.class.php';
$fname ="mike";
$lname = "";
$email = "mike@test.com";

$getresponse = new GetResponse('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$response = $getresponse->addContact(array(
'name'              => $fname . " " . $lname,
'email'             => $email,
'dayOfCycle'        => 0,
'campaign'          => array('campaignId' => '999999999')
));


echo print_r($response);
```